# Don't seem to get the speedup I should in openMP

Tags: c, multithreading

As far as I know, this program should get a speedup of 2 or more when run with 2 threads. Instead of that I get pretty much the same as serially.

```
static void proc_paralelo (int n, char *vprimos,  int nthr) {
```

`omp_set_num_threads(nthr);


int i, j, prim, posiciones;

int raiz_n = sqrt(n);

for (i=1;i < raiz_n; i++)
{
  if (vprimos[i]==0)
    {
       prim=i+1;
       posiciones=ceil((float)(n-(i+prim))/(float)prim);
#pragma omp parallel for private(j) schedule (static, posiciones/omp_get_num_threads())
        for (j=0; j<posiciones; j++){
            vprimos[i+prim+(j*prim)]=1;}
      }
 }
}`

The number of threads I use is 2 (my processor's cores) and the size of `n` is 20000000.

The times I get are:

- serially:       650000000 ns
- in parallel:    630000000 ns

Comment: What is your program supposed to be doing? You should not get a speedup of more than 2x by using 2 threads, btw.

Comment: how long is `posiciones`, typically? If you're going to utilize multiple threads, it should be pretty large.

Comment: Show us how you're measuring the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

By running two threads, you will never (*edit: rarely, see comments*) see more than a 2x speedup. In fact, because no job is perfectly parallelizable, you will likely not even see that. Consider also that starting a new thread takes considerable resources - you will likely not see any gains, and may see performance losses, unless your workload is sufficiently heavy to saturate the CPU for longer than the time it takes to spin up a new thread (for CPU-bound workloads). You will also be limited by shared resource contention as your threads are sharing some hardware or software resources - see comments for some examples.

Comment: There can also be issues such as contention for shared CPU cache, increased paging, and more, that all cut into the speedup that can be realized from parallelization.

Comment: Once in a while, you can see a speedup over 2x from using two cores. An obvious example would be if you're using data that won't fit in one core's cache, but will fit in two cores' caches. In such a case, eliminating a lot of main memory access can improve speed by substantially more than 2x. It's not common, but I have seen it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Now that you mention it, I recall reading about that - and your scenario makes sense. I've not seen it either but I guess the take-away is that saying "never" is pretty silly when talking about the real world.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem here is that your code is almost certainly memory bound, and using a second core isn't increasing your memory bandwidth.

In particular, your `vprimos` is apparently about 20 megabytes, which is too much to fit into cache (at least on most processors). The actual calculation you're doing for a single iteration is utterly trivial (compute an address and write a 1), so even for a single core, you're probably mostly memory bound. Adding a second core saves a tiny bit (probably for parts that *are* in the cache) but that's about it.

In this case, one obvious gain would be from using a single bit to store each Boolean instead of using an entire char. Although it adds some computational overhead, it'll probably save enough memory bandwidth to more than compensate.

One example I threw together a while back (also of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738887/179910)) seems to run about six times as fast as yours for the same size (though it is C++ instead of C).